# How can I send packets between the browser and server with socket.io, but only when there is more than one client?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In my normal setup, the client will emit data to my server regardless of whether or not there is another client to receive it.  How can I make it so that it only sends packets when the user-count is > 1?  I'm using node with socket.io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you would want to listen to the `connection` event on your server (as well as `disconnect`) and maintain a list of clients which are connected in a 'global' variable. When more than 1 client is connected send out a message to all connected clients to know they can start sending messages, like so:

```
var app = require('express').createServer(),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(80);

//setup express

var clients = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    clients.push(socket);

    if (clients.length > 1) {
        io.socket.emit('start talking');
    }

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        var index = clients.indexOf(socket);

        clients = clients.slice(0, index).concat(clients.slice(index + 1));

        if (clients.length <= 1) {
            io.sockets.emit('quiet time');
        };
    });
});
```

<strike>*Note: I'm making an assumption here that the socket is passed to the disconnect event, I'm pretty sure it is but haven't had a chance to test.*</strike>

The `disconnect` event wont receive the socket passed into it but because the event handler is registered within the closure scope of the initial connection you will have access to it.

Comment: if a socket wasn't passed     on("disconnect") , what would you suggest instead?

Comment: I don't know if it is or not myself, I haven't had the time to test it out

Comment: by the way, I mean, I'm using express, but is there a viable alternative to it?

Comment: why do you say "if clients is less than or equal to one".  if there there are no clients left, then wouldn't it be pointless to emit to them?